# Using Elasticsearch DSL Query with Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, elasticsearch, querydsl

I am trying to connect from mapreduce to Elasticsearch. There is a great [tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapreduce.html) which I used. To query elasticsearch it uses [uri search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) which works fine:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("es.resource", "radio/artists/");            
conf.set("es.query", "?q=me*");
```

I am curious if it is possible to use [query dsl](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) somehow. I did not find anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it is possible to use Query DSL and it is quite easy. All you need to do is to edit query to starts with `{` and ends with `}`. So it will look like:

```
conf.set("es.query", { "query" : { "term" : { "user" : "costinl" } } });
```

Or it is possible to use external `json` file:

```
conf.set("es.query", "some.json");
```

More about this is [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html).